# What can we say about bounded sequence?

Tags: calculus

$a_n$ is a sequence
If $(a_n)$ is bounded can  we say that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0$?
And if $(a_{n+1} - a_n)$ is bounded can we say that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} = 0$?

And in general what can i conclude about a sequence if i know that it is bounded?
Thanks

Comment: If the sequence is bounded by M, use squeeze theorem to prove the first statement.  Sadly, try the second one with $a_n = n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, first, I alway assume that in your limit you meant to write $n\to\infty$ instead of $x\to\infty$, else your expression doesn't really make any sense.

For the first one, consider the following: $|\frac{a_n}{n}|\leq |\frac{c}{n}|$. What can you say about the limit of the latter expression?

For the second one, consider the sequence $a_n=n$. Is the difference $a_{n+1}-a_n$ bounded? What about the limit $\frac{a_n}{n}$?

Generally, if a sequence is bounded, and you are in a complete metric space, then you know there exists a convergent subsequence, additionally to your first statement. At least, that's what jumps to my mind talking about bounded sequences. There's certainly many more properties they have, but if you could be a bit more precise what you actually want to know, it'd make thinking of them much easier.

Comment: if $a_n = n$ doesn't it say that the first sequence would be {1, 2, 3, 4...} and the second one would be {1,1,1,1...} and $1 \over n$=0 when $n$ -> $\infty$ (for the second part)?

Comment: Pardon me, what exactly do you mean by 'first sequence' and 'second sequence'? If by first sequence you mean $a_n$, and by the second you mean $a_{n+1}-a_n$, then you are correct. Especially note that the second sequence is bounded. And, yes, in this case we'd have $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n}\to 0$, however, your question was about $\lim \frac{a_n}{n}$, not $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n}$. Take a look at $\frac{a_n}{n}$ from here, and try to determine the limit.

Comment: Yes you understood me :) and thanks I skiped this info

Comment: Just to be sure about the first sequence how did the $a_n$ is bounded info helped you in your assumption($|a_n \over n| \le |c \over n|$)?

Comment: We have $|a_n|<c$. Division by $n$ (note that $n$ is positive, hence we can pull it into the absolute) leads to $|\frac{a_n}{n}|\leq \frac{c}{n}$. At least, that's what I think you mean, you kinda messed up the code there ;)

Comment: Yea this is what I meant(you called M c right?) Im not sure where I gone wrong with this code kinda new to matjax thanks for all your efforts I'll accept your answer and sorry if i asked too many questions it's just that I dont have a teacher and i need to learn it alone

Comment: Yup, I called my constant $c$. As in, *c*onstant. Don't worry about that, it just takes practice - and rely on the person being asked to tell you if there are too many questions, as long as you don't understand something and have given it an honest effort, I feel you're more than within your rights to ask.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, yes. Note that if $|a_{n}| \leq M$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{-M}{n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{M}{n}$$

Now apply the squeeze theorem.

The second, however, is not true. Take $a_{n} = n$.

Comment: In my book it says that sequence is bounded if $|a_n| < M$ and not $\le$ am I missing something?

Comment: @kfir124: it's not terribly material in this case. This proof works just fine with your definition.

Comment: Will the squeeze theorem work without the $\le$? I've never learnt it but I watched a video about it and it seemed like the $\le$ plays a big part

Comment: It does, actually. Only, what you need to be careful of is that in a limit, $<$ can transform to a $\leq$ - look at the constant sequence $0$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. We have $0<\frac{1}{n}$, but the limits are the same, hence only $\leq$. In fact, if you have two sequences with the same limit, $a_n,b_n$, and a $c_n$, such that $a_n<c_n<b_n$, then you can surely say that $a_n\leq c_n \leq b_n$, since $<$ is actually a stronger condition. Or have I misunderstood your question here? Also, you might note that if $|a_n|\leq M$, then $|a_n|<M+1$, thus the definitions of boundedness are equivalent.

Comment: @SomeMathStudent: well said. Thanks for clarifying!